# Limit a Wordpress user to see only pages and posts

Tags: wordpress, security, user-roles

How to limit a WordPress user to see only `pages` and `posts` in his `panel`? I want other menus like `Appearance, Plugins, Settings, ...` be hidden to that user.

How to do it?

I've searched a lot about this, but most of the results are talking about limiting user to specific posts and pages, not main WordPress facilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Justin Tadlock's [Members plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/members/) is exactly what you're looking for. You can control what user roles exist on your site and set the permissions for each role.

Hope that helps

Dan